# Wildcard binding when using the Azure Accelerator for web roles

Tags: azure

This relates specifically to the Windows Azure Accelerator for web roles.

How can I configure the Website manager web role so that it only responds on a certain host name and have one of the hosted sites used a wildcard binding?

So far I've given the web role a specific hostname and added a binding to my child site with an empty host name. Looking in IIS on the remote machine, everything looks fine.

However, I'm finding that the wildcard entry has little effect and I can only get to the web site if I set up specific bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the way in which Azure handles "wildcard" bindings. Specifically, a binding with IP "All Unassigned" doesn't actually work. I've yet to find out why - MS support are working on that one.

I've added the patch to fix the Accelerator on codeplex - http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/workitem/5

[Update]

Have blogged full details at http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/azure-accelerator-wildcard-bindings

Answer (score -1):

Simple, open ServiceDefinition.csdef and add hostheader to WebRole sites bindings. Result should look somewhat like this:

```
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="webadmin.mytest.com"  />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

Unfortunately sites without defined header still wont work anywere else than on local machine (remote desktop) and will fail with:

**Service Unavailable**

---

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: so how does this help me exactly?